# User info not sent to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a : create account page for a website. The problem is no data gets sent to the database.

Here is what I put :

```
include 'databaseconnection.php';
if (isset($_POST['submitbutton'])) {

  include 'databaseconnection.php';

  $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
  $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);

  //error handlers
  // check for empty feilds

  if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($password) || empty($email) || empty($username)) {
      header("Location: signupcode.php");
      exit();
  } else {
      if (!preg_match("/ˆ[a-zA-Z]*$/",$first) || !preg_match("/ˆ[a-zA-Z]*$/",$last)) {
          header("Location: signupcode.php?signup=empty");
          exit();
      } else {
          //email check
          if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
              header("Location: signupcode.php?error");
              exit();
          } else {
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
              $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
              $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
              if ($resultcheck > 0) {
                  header("Location: signupcode.php?error");
                  exit();
              }  else {
                  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
                  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                  $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                  if ($resultcheck > 0) {
                      header("Location: signupcode.php?error");
                      exit();
                  } else {
                      //hashing the Password
                      $hasedpassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, lastname, password, email)
                            VALUES ('$username', '$first', '$last', '$hasedpassword', '$email');";
                      $dbservername= "localhost";
                      $dbusername= "root";
                      $dbpassword= "";
                      $dbname = "landingpage-login";

                      $conn = mysqli_connect($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

                      mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                      header("Location: signupcode.php");
                      exit();
                 }
            }
        }
    }
  }

}

 ?>
```

The problem is that when I go to localhost:8080/php my admin nothing shows up in my table : users in the database : landingpage-login. Every time I check it, it's empty, nothing in the username, password etc...

Comment: Also you are open to SQL injections. .. If you start fresh i would suggest you to use PDO

Comment: You could stop so many levels of indentation by the fact that your `if` statements usually end in an `exit()`, so you don't actually need the `else`.

Comment: It's also worth learning about SQL injection and prepared statements - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

First off you can't have more than one `else` statement in any programming language. Your code reaches the first `else` and execute that block.

Try having

```
 else if (!preg_match("/ˆ[a-zA-Z]*$/",$first) || !preg_match("/ˆ[a-zA-Z]*$/",$last)){//Code}
```

Comment: How to I incorporate that with :

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  ($resultcheck > 0) {
    header("Location: signupcode.php?error");
    exit();

Comment: because I can't put a else if since the condition is below